# Make chapter appear in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I want to customize the way the table of contents is provided by LaTeX :

Here is my (minimal) working code (my real preambule is about 300 lines) :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

% For French
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

% A numbered chapter
\chapter{First}

%An unnumbered chapter
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

I want to get a table of contents like that :

```
Partie I - First Part . . . . 1

Chapitre 1 - First . . . . . .2
Appendix . . . . . . . . . . .3
```

With my code I get :

```
I First Part . . . . . . . . . 1
1 First . . . . . . . . . . . .2
Appendix . . . . . . . . . . . 3
```

In fact managing the unnumbered chapters is simple, I did solve this in my code. But when the chapters are numbered I don't know how to change it in the TOC. 
I also want the bookmarks in the pdf (I compile with pdflatex) to be the same as in the TOC i.e here for example "Chapitre 1 - First"

Also, but still not the more important, if it is possible I would like to get the "Chapitre" of "Partie" word in small caps.

I am convinced that this question may have been asked before, but I didn't found an answer to my question.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily do that using `titlesec` and `titletoc`. B.t.w., why ‘appendix’ in French, instead of « appendice » or « annexe »?

Comment: About the "Appendix" thing, it is just an exemple, I will use "Annexe" for sure ! I will get a look at the packages you mentioned, thank you

Comment: Beware the main problem is for parts, because it is implemented in a non-standard way by basic latex. You'll have to re-define the way they're displayed first to have the possibility to define the way they appear in the table of contents. Use the `newparttoc` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I use standard features of the `tocloft` package.  Note, however, that page 10 of the `tocloft` documentation indicates that `\cftpartaftersnum` **DOES NOT WORK** for the standard document classes.  Thus, I cannot add an en-dash following the part number.

EDITED to make the words "Partie" and "Chapitre" in small caps.  EDITED to center the chapter's en-dash in the white space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\textsc{Partie}\ }
\renewcommand\cftpartaftersnum{\ --}% ACCORDING TO p.10 OF THE DOCS, THIS MAY NOT WORK
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\bigskip}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\textsc{Chapitre}\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\hfill--\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{3.2cm}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
% For French
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

% A numbered chapter
\chapter{First}

%An unnumbered chapter
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is quite what I want, so thank you ! There is a problem : I wanted something like "Chapitre 1 - First" and not "Chapitre - 1 First". I think what I want is more difficult than what you did, because the chapter number has to be inserted in another place

Comment: @JohnMarjan Play with the commands `\cftpartpresnum{}`, `\cftpartafterpnum{}`, `\cftchappresnum{}` as their name is self-explanatory.

Comment: @JohnMarjan - Hint: change `\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Partie --\ }` to `\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Partie}` and change `\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\bigskip}` to `\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{ --\ }`, etc.

Comment: @JohnMarjan I have revised, though there appears to be a documented package issue with adding the dash after the part number.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That seems to work perfectly except for the bookmarks (I accepted already) : the bookmarks (whith the use of `hyperref`) are "First Part" and "First" and not "Partie I First part" and "Chapitre 1 - First"

Comment: @JohnMarjan I have no experience with bookmarks, but I will poke around the site a bit.  If I come across something, I will amend my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes this is very nice of you ! I keep searching myself to.

Comment: @JohnMarjan There is a macro `\texorpdfstring{<tex code>}{<pdf code>}` that allows different things to be processed by TeX vs. the PDF internal code.  Thus, defining `\newcommand\Bpart[1]{\part{\texorpdfstring{}{Partie -- }#1}}` and using `\Bpart{First part}` will produce a PDF document in which the bookmark reads `1 Partie - First part`.  I haven't figured out without getting into the guts of `\part` on how to insert the `\texorpdfstring` before the part number.  But this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39025/discussion-between-john-marjan-and-steven-b-segletes).

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with parts with `tocloft` is always a pain.

I can propose two patches for the `book` class and two alternative settings, depending on the desired alignment of chapter titles. No attempt in aligning part titles is done, because Roman numbers are too variable in width.

### First proposal

The chapter titles are not aligned with each other if there are more than nine of them. Before rejecting this, consider that between two chapter titles there will be some section titles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\numberline}
  {\chapternumberline}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\partnumberline[1]{\textsc{Partie} #1 -- }
\newcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\textsc{\chaptername} #1 -- }

\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\nobreak\bigskip}

\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

% A numbered chapter
\chapter{First}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Tenth}

%An unnumbered chapter
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second proposal

Chapter titles are aligned, and the number is set flush right (so leaving a hole when it has just one digit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\numberline}
  {\chapternumberline}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\partnumberline[1]{\textsc{Partie} #1 -- }
\newcommand\chapternumberline[1]{%
  \textsc{\chaptername} %
  \ifnum#1<10 \hphantom{0}\fi
  #1 -- %
}

\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\nobreak\bigskip}

\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

% A numbered chapter
\chapter{First}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Tenth}

%An unnumbered chapter
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that's a great work ! By the way, where did you learn how to create your own macros ?

Comment: @JohnMarjan The idea is the same as in the `memoir` class, that has separate “numberline” macros for parts, chapters and sections. It makes things much easier. Add 30+ years of experience and thorough reading of the TeXbook. `;-)`

Comment: @JohnMarjan egreg is one of the foremost LaTeX experts in the world.  he wrote `xpatch` and a number of other indispensible packages.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes So he is very humble ! Respect to his answers...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You're surely referring to `kantlipsum`. `;-)`

Comment: Those who can, do.  Those who Kant, lipsum!  Indeed, indispensible.