# Part cross reference name clash with redefinition of \thepart

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, parts

I want to use some automatic cross referencing (I am using `hyperref` in the whole document which I customized) to write something like :

```
We see in \autoref{partname} that
```

To print :

```
We see in part I that
```

The problem is I redefined the part name for my TOC and here is the MWE for my problem :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Ecrire en français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace} % Pour les espaces automatiques

% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-.4cm}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}\label{first}

\chapter{Intro}

We will deal with \autoref{first}

We will deal with \ref{first} 

When I add ponctuation : \autoref{first}. It is not beautiful. 
\end{document}
```

Giving me :

[image]

All I want is to change the capital P into a non capital letter, supress the dash and get ok with the space after. Since I can create a command, all I need is answer this precise question :

> How do I get access to the part numbers, for example `I`. I tried with `\getrefnumber` but that gives "Partie I -"

Am I stuck with this problem or is there a mean of getting both my TOC and auto reference system ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xpatch` isn't needed here

Comment: I removed `xpatch`. @Mico I don't understand, there is no `:` in my labels !

Comment: @JohnMarjan: that `\hspace{...}` in your `\thepart` is not really useful, in my point of view. The `\autorefname` is using `\partname`, not `\thepart`. By using `\thepartie` with the the negative `\hspace` value, your text `It is not beautiful` is shifted back and overprints the `--` characters.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the `\hspace` was for adding space in the TOC, it was a sort of "trick" I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `\hspace` in a `\the...` command -- it screws up references (formats)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Ecrire en français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace} % Pour les espaces automatiques

% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part}}% --\hspace{-0.4cm}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{First Part}\label{first}

\chapter{Intro} 


We will deal with \autoref{first}

We will deal with \ref{first} 

When I add ponctuation : \autoref{first}. It is beautiful! 

When I add ponctuation : \autoref{second}. It is not beautiful. 


% Now bad:

\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-0.4cm}}
\part{Second Part}\label{second}

Foo



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** -- Curing the `--` issue!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

% Ecrire en français
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace} % Pour les espaces automatiques


\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\partnamedivider}{\textendash}

\makeatletter
% Must be done here, before tocloft 'screws' up the definition of \@part
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\ \partnamedivider\ #1}
}{\typeout{Success!!!!!}}{\typeout{Failed!!!!!}}
\makeatother

% Part name in TOC
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part}}


\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}\label{first}

\chapter{Intro} 


We will deal with \autoref{first}

We will deal with \ref{first} 

When I add ponctuation : \autoref{first}. It is beautiful! 

When I add ponctuation : \autoref{second}. It is not beautiful. 


% Now bad:

\renewcommand{\thepart}{Partie \Roman{part} --\hspace{-0.4cm}}
\part{Second Part}\label{second}

Foo



\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the `--` in the part name for my toc. I tried your document and the toc has changed.

Comment: @JohnMarjan: Your post does not reveal that `--` is essential at all

Comment: Thats because I fortgot `\tableofcontents`in the MWE ^^

Comment: @JohnMarjan: See the update at the bottom, please

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cleveref`, it's much more powerful. I used the patches from [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306849/4427)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%% patches to \@part and \@chapter must
%%% be done before loading hyperref
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\numberline}
  {\chapternumberline}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[french,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcommand\partnumberline[1]{\textsc{Partie} #1 -- }
\newcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\textsc{\chaptername} #1 -- }

\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\par\nobreak\bigskip}

\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}\label{first}

\chapter{Intro}

We will deal with \cref{first}

We will deal with \ref{first} 

When I add ponctuation : \cref{first}. It is not beautiful. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw your other answer. It seems clear to me that `cleverref` is powerfull, but since I wrote a whole preambule with `hyperref` it is long to change everything (I customize the `hyperref` for figures, subfigures to make them small caps, for the equations to be like "equation (1)"). When I have time I will change for sure !

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing it :

`\hyperref[<part label>]{Partie \Roman{part}}`

is doing the job, then I just have to redefine a new command for it. Yes this in not elegant since there will be `\autoref` in the text and `\MyCommand` for parts.

Still if there is better, let me now :)